# Stopping rule in the rlm() function for MASS package

Tags: r, regression, convergence, robust

When I looked at the source code for the `rlm()` function:

```
    irls.rrxwr <- function(x, w, r)
    {
        w <- sqrt(w)
        max(abs((matrix(r * w, 1L, length(r)) %*% x)/
                sqrt(matrix(w, 1L, length(r)) %*% (x^2))))/sqrt(sum(w * r^2))
    }
```

above code has been used as a stopping rule where `x` is the matrix of predictor variables, `w` is a weight vector and `r` is the residual vector, i.e., $r = y - Xb$.

If I write this expression using maths then it becomes
$$
(\text{max}\ r^\top W X / \sqrt{\text{diag}(X^\top W X)}) / r^\top W r
$$

where $W$ is a diagonal matrix with elements $\sqrt{w}$ and $diag(\cdot)$ extracts the diagonal elements.

What is the logic behind using this as the stopping rule?